# плавное выпадающее меню

Tags: html, css

Где нужно написать transition чтобы выпадающее меню открывалась плавнее?

```css
.container {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 100px;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  background-color: brown;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}

.menu:hover .content {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">Menu
    <div class="content">
      <a href="">dd</a>
      <a href="">dd</a>
      <a href="">dd</a>
      <a href="">dd</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать @keyframes, что бы не дублировать ответ- посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879228/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E) на мой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 100px;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  background-color: brown;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition-property: opacity, visibility;
  transition-duration: .3s, 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s, .3s;
}

.menu:hover .content {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">Menu
    <div class="content">
      <a href="">dd</a>
      <a href="">dd</a>
      <a href="">dd</a>
      <a href="">dd</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```