# Высота выпадающего подменю

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтобы высота выпадающего меню подстраивалась под содержимое, при этом сохранить такой эффект выпадания (пример ниже), при `height: auto;` почему-то не срабатывает `transition`. Можно добиться примерно такого же эффекта при помощи `transfom: scaleY(0);` потом при наведении на пункт меню менять на `transfom: scaleY(1);` но тогда содержимое сжимается во время трансформации.

```css
ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
}
.menu {
 font-size: 0;
}
.menu-item {
 padding: 3px 15px;
 font-size: 16px;
 background-color: #eee;
 display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown {
 position: relative;
}
.dropdown:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 55%;
 right: 4px;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 border-left: 4px solid transparent;
 border-right: 4px solid transparent;
 border-top: 6px solid #666;
 transition: 0.3s;
}
.dropdown:hover ul {
 height: 150px;
}
.dropdown:hover::after {
 border-left: 4px solid transparent;
 border-right: 4px solid transparent;
 border-top: none;
 border-bottom: 6px solid #666;
}
.dropdown ul {
 height: 0;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: #ddd;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: 0.3s;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 0;
}
.dropdown li {
 padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item dropdown">
   Menu 1
   <ul>
    <li>Sub menu</li>
    <li>Sub menu</li>
    <li>Sub menu</li>
    <li>Sub menu</li>
    <li>Sub menu</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">Menu 2</li>
  <li class="menu-item dropdown">
   Menu 3
   <ul>
    <li>Sub menu</li>
    <li>Sub menu</li>
    <li>Sub menu</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">Menu 4</li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `max-height`

Пример

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu {
  font-size: 0;
}

.menu-item {
  padding: 3px 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  right: 4px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #666;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.dropdown:hover ul {
  max-height: 999px;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown:hover::after {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #666;
}

.dropdown ul {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
}

.dropdown li {
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item dropdown">
      Menu 1
      <ul>
        <li>Sub menu</li>
        <li>Sub menu</li>
        <li>Sub menu</li>
        <li>Sub menu</li>
        <li>Sub menu</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">Menu 2</li>
    <li class="menu-item dropdown">
      Menu 3
      <ul>
        <li>Sub menu</li>
        <li>Sub menu</li>
        <li>Sub menu</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">Menu 4</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что надо!)

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так. Эффект выпадания меню можно менять в @keyframes hover. Sub-menu позиционировано абсолютно(position:absolute;) и margin-ом подвинуто в низ на величину padding-а в .5rem. А ширина и высота будет автоматом подстраиваться по содержимому потому что для ul.menu  position:relative.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.main-menu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

ul.menu {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .5rem 0rem;
}

ul li+li {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
}

ul li:first-child {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
}

ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
}

ul li ul.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul.sub-menu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: .5rem;
  animation: hover 1s;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes hover {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-menu">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="/">Menu</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="/">Menu 2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="/">Sub menu 1</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="/">Sub menu 2</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="/">Sub menu 3</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="/">Sub menu 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="/">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="/">Menu 4</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="/">Sub menu 1</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="/">Sub menu 2</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="/">Sub menu 3</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu-item"><a href="/">Sub menu 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="/">Menu 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: С прозрачностью всё хорошо и в моём варианте, но мне надо чтобы высота с 0 до auto менялась плавно, но получается только с 0 до фиксированной высоты, других вариантов я не могу найти чтобы сохранить такой эффект который мне нужен (не opacity)